# How to make creat-react-app build listen on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost?

Tags: reactjs

I have a create-react-app bootstrapped project i want to deploy on an instance. Right now there are two ways that I have tried to set up the deployment which only ends up setting the port and not the host.

My project architecture is as below

```
Project
- Frontend
- Backend
```

My main issue is that although I am able to set the port on create-react-app build I cannot set the hostname to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost.

In create-react app i hardcoded `HOST=0.0.0.0` and `PORT=443` in the start script.

Other thing i tried is have a script the serves the pages on port 443. Build serves on port 443 but not on 0.0.0.0.

Create-react-app scripts

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=443 react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
```

Basic script at the root of the project

```
"scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "client": "cd frontend && npm start",
        "client-prod": "cd frontend/build && npm install -g serve && serve -s build -l 443",
        "server": "cd backend && npm start",
        "sass": "node-sass -w frontend/source/styles/ -o frontend/source/styles/ --recursive",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\" ",
        "prod": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client-prod\" "
    },
```

The development on localhost works fine but i need to able to serve my build pages on 0.0.0.0:443 instead of localhost

Answer (score 1):

env file instead in the root of your project and set HOST=0.0.0.0 and if you also want to disable the automatic browser opening when you type yarn or npm start, you can also set BROWSER=none. Check this link for more info https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

As per the [advanced configuration](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/docusaurus/docs/advanced-configuration.md) page for React, the HOST environment variable does not apply when you deploy (in the table, see column Production, it says **Ignored**).

This means that HOST is not the way to set up your deployment.  HOST is only functional when doing `npm start` in your development PC.

When you do `npm run build`, you get a `/build` folder with all the contents of the *compiled* application, and you get NO HTTP server.  The HTTP server for deployment you select, configure and deploy on your own.  See the [deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment) page to understand this fully.

So, in short:  HOST is only for local development & testing.  In deployment, you set up your NGINX, Apache or any other server in the way that server is configured.